# Show two irreducible polynomials from a polynomial field cannot share a root

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

The problem is as follows:

Let $F$ be a field and $K \leqslant F$. Let $f(x)$ and $g(x) \in K[x]$, where $f$ and $g$ are irreducible and not associates of one another.

Show that $f$ and $g$ do not share any roots in $F$.

Here is my attempt:

AFSOC $\exists a \in F$ s.t. $f(a) = g(a) = 0$.

Then $\exists b(x), c(x) \in F[x]$ s.t. $b(x)(x-a) = f(x)$, and $c(x)(x-a) = g(x)$.

Here is where I am a little unsure of my work. Since $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ need not be in $K[x]$, I am not sure if I can make the following claim, but anyways I will proceed.

Since $x-a$ cannot be a unit, it must be the case that both $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ are units in $F$.

Thus $f(x) = b(x)c^{-1}(x)c(x)(x-a) = b(x)c^{-1}(x)g(x)$

Contradicting that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not associates.

Any hints/feedback would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'll be honest, your work doesn't make much sense past a certain point.

Specifically not only do $b(x)$ and $c(x)$ not need to be in $K$, they probably aren't since they're polynomials in $F[x]$, so they're not in $K$ unless they're of degree 0 and also in $K$ rather than $F$. The bigger issue is when you conclude that $b$ and $c$ (I'm dropping the $(x)$ notation, since I find it clunky) are units. That's not true (a priori), since $f$ and $g$ are irreducible in $K[x]$ not $F[x]$, and ignoring the issue of whether $f$ and $g$ are in $K[x]$, $(x-a)$ is not in $K[x]$ either, so the factorizations $f=(x-a)b$ and $g=(x-a)c$ are not factorizations in $K[x]$.

There are several approaches here, depending on your level.

The first is to use minimal polynomials. Since $a\in F$ is the root of some polynomial over $K$ (being the root of both $f$ and $g$), it has some nonzero polynomial of smallest degree in $K[x]$ of which it is a root. Using the division algorithm, you can prove that this polynomial, $m$ has the property that it divides any polynomial with coefficients in $K$ for which $a$ is a root. Thus $m\mid f$ and $m\mid g$, but since $m$ is nonzero and has a root it has positive degree, so since $m\mid f$, and $f$ is irreducible, $m$ and $f$ are associates, and similarly $m$ and $g$ are associates. Contradiction.

The other approach is essentially the same, but phrased in more abstract language.
Let $\phi_a : K[x]\to F$ be the evaluation at $a$ homomorphism, noting that it is nonzero, since $\phi_a(1)=1$. $f$ and $g$ are both in the kernel of this map and both irreducible, so they must generate the kernel, since $K[x]$ is a PID (and they're irreducible). Thus $f\mid g$ and $g\mid f$, contradiction.

Comment: Yeah I was pretty sure my work made no sense. We have not learned about minimal polynomials and in fact they are about an entire chapter ahead of what we are doing in our textbook. Our professor says that we should always be able to do a problem using what has previously been introduced in the text, so I am guessing I am overlooking some simpler way. I will think about your solution nonetheless. Thanks :)

Comment: I decided to read through the definition of minimal polynomial real quick, and using what the textbook provides as a definition made the problem pretty simple, so thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

By Bezout, $\,f,g$ coprime $\,\Rightarrow  h f + h' g = 1\ $ so evaluating at $\,x=a\,$ yields $\,0 = 1\,$ in $F\, \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

Comment: Very nice (+1)!